# AngularJS isolated directives inheriting surrounding or parent scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have put up my code at jsbin: http://jsbin.com/fewom/1/edit

If any one can guide me, what am I doing wrong there. I have specified scope to be isolated inside myDirective with scope: {} but still when i write myProperty inside my directive in html I am able to read myProperty.

I was using AngularJS https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js

When i changed my library to it started to work,

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.js

then I have tried,

Angular JS version 1.2.16
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js

and

Angular JS version 1.3.0-beta.5
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.min.js

and the problem for isolated scoping shows up again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a controller, so nothing ties your directive to your html.

Change your js to this (I just added a blank controller):

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {}
        };     
    })
.controller('ctrl', function (){

});
```

and in your html, change to this (referenced the controller):

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='ctrl'>
```

Comment: I have put a controller in there now: http://jsbin.com/fewom/2/edit kindly see and give feedback

Comment: also see this code: http://jsbin.com/eguDEpa/1/edit there is not controller there, just a module and a directive, so it should have anything to do with the controller in my opinion

Comment: Interesting--I thought a controller was required.  In any case, my answer really doesn't answer your question.  I will look a bit more.

Comment: updated my code per your comments but the result is the same as before: http://jsbin.com/fewom/3/edit

Comment: very interesting I have updated the library version from https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js
to
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.js and now it's working, there must be something with angular library version

Comment: check my comments above again, I think it has to do with angularjs versions, something probably is not right or has changed.

Comment: yeah, sounds like you have it figured out.  I really jumped in when I saw an obvious problem with your setup (missing the controller), so my answer has nothing to do with your question.  Anyway, if it looks like a regression in the beta version, you might want to file an issue with your repro case.